# TypeError at /api/products/1 save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I'm trying to make rest API using django rest framework, I want to make it so that when I make a patch request, I can update the model or objects but when I try to do that, I get TypeError at /api/products/1
save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' error

views.py

```
class DetailView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, id ,format=None):
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=id)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(product)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def patch(self, request, id, format=None):
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=id)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(Product, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arpit/anaconda3/envs/djangoProject/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/arpit/anaconda3/envs/djangoProject/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/arpit/anaconda3/envs/djangoProject/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/arpit/anaconda3/envs/djangoProject/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/arpit/anaconda3/envs/djangoProject/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/arpit/anaconda3/envs/djangoProject/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/arpit/anaconda3/envs/djangoProject/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/arpit/anaconda3/envs/djangoProject/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/arpit/anaconda3/envs/djangoProject/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/arpit/Desktop/Coding Projects/React-ECom/backend/API/views.py", line 39, in patch
    serializer.save()
  File "/home/arpit/anaconda3/envs/djangoProject/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 200, in save
    self.instance = self.update(self.instance, validated_data)
  File "/home/arpit/anaconda3/envs/djangoProject/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 983, in update
    instance.save()

Exception Type: TypeError at /api/products/1
Exception Value: save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Product

class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [ 'id','name','price','description']
```

Comment: can you please share full error traceback

Comment: Sure! I edited my post and added traceback

Comment: there might be an error in your **ProductSerializer**. can you show ProductSerializer

Comment: I added serializers.py too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```py
serializer = ProductSerializer(Product, data=request.data)
```

I think you meant to pass in the `product` instance and not the `Product` class.

```py
product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=id)
serializer = ProductSerializer(product, data=request.data)
```